# Regex to capture repeating pattern of variable length

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to prepare a repeating pattern of console arguments
to run through CommandLineParser (nuget). I am half way there, but i can't manage to get the `secondmatch` as an individual match.

Essentially what i want to do is a chainable list of invocations.

Each invocation should start with `-t`

#### My current regex

`(((?=-t ).+(?=-t ))|((?=-t ).+))`

#### Input string:

```
-t fistarg -tfalsepositive -a wasdf- -t secondmatch -t thirdmatch
```

#### Current matches:

`-t fistarg -tfalsepositive -a wasdf- -t secondmatch`

`-t thirdmatch`

#### Expected matches:

`-t fistarg -tfalsepositive -a wasdf-`

`-t secondmatch`

`-t thirdmatch`

Comment: Maybe `(?=-t ).+?(?=-t |$)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes - make it an answer :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i always thought .+ is equivalent to .*? would you care to enlighten me on what's the difference in using it with a +?

Comment: Well, if there should be at least one char, use `+?`. Else, use `*?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
-t .+?(?=-t |$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-t+.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d-t+%7c%24%29&i=-t+fistarg+-tfalsepositive+-a+wasdf-+-t+secondmatch+-t+thirdmatch)

**Details**

- `-t` - a `-t` substring
- `.+?` - a space followed with any 1+ chars (use `*?` to match 0+ chars) other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=-t |$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a `-t` substring or end of string immediately to the right of the current locaiton.

Comment: Pure curiosity, is there any reason you've used RegexStorm rather than the traditional Regex101 ?

Comment: @Paul-Etienne It is a C# related question, and regex101 does not support .NET. Although this pattern will work very similarly in PCRE, JS and Python, still, RegexStorm is a better *proof* the pattern will work with .NET regex engine.

Comment: If `-t xxxx-t xxxx` should be one match then the regex fails on it.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `-t xxxx-t xxxx` should match as `-t xxxx-t xxxx` (1 match) - so the regex he posted is correct as it is.

Comment: @Dbl have you checked. There is two match there.

Comment: Guys, if the `-t` must be matched as a "whole word", just add `\B` before `-t`, `@"\B-t .+?(?=-t |$)"`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Are you sure? I've tried it in regex101, regexstorm and from within my application. works fine in all 3.

Comment: `\B` will fix regex but in both places.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you're correct actually. Good catch.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan While the regex did what it should, for my actual purpose of console parsing your consideration is very relevant.

Comment: @Dbl Then, probably `@"\B-t .+?(?=\B-t |$)"` will be more appropriate.

Comment: I will suggest to use `@"-t .+?(?= -t |$)"` instead.

Comment: Or `@" -t .+?(?= -t |$)"`